# Handling Timeout error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After using timeout:

```
 status = Timeout::timeout(5) {
  # Something that should be interrupted if it takes too much time...
}
```

I got this Timeout error:

```
/Users/galharth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize': execution expired (Timeout::Error)
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `open'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `block in connect'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:87:in `timeout'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `connect'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:632:in `start'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mechanize-1.0.0/lib/mechanize.rb:527:in `fetch_page'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mechanize-1.0.0/lib/mechanize.rb:259:in `get'
```

What should I do?

Comment: `status = Timeout::timeout(5) { puts "ok" }` Failed?

Comment: I've just tested on ruby1-9-2-p180 - no issue

Comment: My gut tells me you should make an effort to prevent the timeout from occurring, if possible. Can you split this single request into multiple smaller requests?

Comment: @yock, You can't control the behavior of the internet. One request for a small page can take minutes. It has nothing to do with the number of requests, it's the responsiveness of the host returning the request.

Comment: That all depends on the reason for the lengthy response time. If the API call is slow because it's returning a lot of data, you could probably break that call into many smaller calls. So, no, you aren't always at the behest of the Internet.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, that's expected behaviour of [`Timeout`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/classes/Timeout.html#M004167). If the block takes too long, its execution gets terminated and an exception thrown.

You would probably like to catch the exception and handle it appropriately:

```
require 'timeout'
begin
  status = Timeout::timeout(5) {
    # Something that should be interrupted if it takes too much time...
  }
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts 'That took too long, exiting...'
end
```

Comment: `Timeout` common exception is `Timeout::Error`. Here is another issue

Comment: Will a rescue block handle Timeout::Error?

Comment: @yock "Will a rescue block handle Timeout::Error?" From the [Timeout documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/classes/Timeout.html#M004167): `If the block execution terminates before sec seconds has passed, it returns the result value of the block. If not, it terminates the execution and raises exception (which defaults to Timeout::Error).`

Comment: I recognize that it throws an "exception", but its type is "Interrupt", is it not? AFAIK, a rescue block only catches StandardError and its subtypes.

Comment: You can indeed `rescue` it. `Timeout::Error.ancestors` gives `Timeout::Error` `RuntimeError` `StandardError` `Exception` `Object` `Kernel` `BasicObject`

Answer (score 0):

```
uri = URI.parse("https://example.com")
        # Full control
        http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
        http.use_ssl = true
        #http.read_timeout = 500
        request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
        request.set_form_data({"locationcode" => "999", "sublocationcode" => "1"})
        response = http.request(request)
        render :json => response.body
```